# Is there public transport between Quimper Airport and the city centre?

Tags: public-transport, france, airport-transfer, brittany, uip

Quimper Cornouaille Airport (UIP) is located about 10km from Quimper, near the village of Pluguffan. That's a little bit more than I fancy walking, so I'm wondering if there's any public transport between the airport / somewhere near the airport and the centre of Quimper?

In case it matters, one way will be during the week mid-afternoon, the other on a Sunday, which might be more problematic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official site of the airport](http://www.quimper.aeroport.fr/services_taxis_bus.php) says

> Bus number 25 connects the Quimper Cornouaille Airport to the town
>   centre of Quimper in less than 30 minutes. The bus station is located
>   outside the airport.

[Here](http://www.qub.fr/) is the official site of the bus service, it seems french only but there is a nice route calculator which isn't hard to use and it helps to plan the trip in great detail.

Comment: Thanks! From that, I've found [this timetable from the airport to the city](http://www.qub.fr/fichiers/hap_download/saison3/QUB_ligne_25_Aeroport_-_Aerborzh_vers_Quimper.pdf), and [this](http://www.qub.fr/fichiers/hap_download/saison3/QUB_ligne_25_Aeroport_-_Aerborzh_vers_Pluguffan_Ti_Lipig.pdf) for the return. Nothing on Sundays though :(

Comment: There are no buses to the airport on Sundays and on bank holidays. But there will be taxis. If you want to be 200% sure, call one of the companies and book a taxi for you departure.